# Reference a UILabel name as a variable

Tags: iphone, ios5, nsstring, uilabel

If I have a `UILabel`:

```
USD_time.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %.2dm %.2ds", pre, min, sec];
```

Is it possible to reference the `UILabel` as a variable?

Ex:

```
NSString *myLabel = @"USD_time";
myLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %.2dm %.2ds", pre, min, sec];
```

I know this does not work, I am unsure what the proper format would be.  Also I am unsure what this is called.

Thank so much.

Comment: wat do u want to achieve by using variable "Variable"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read up on [Key Value Coding,](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html) it's just the thing you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Think it simple. Take an object `UILabel *myLabel`, then take a `NSString` object  `NSString  *myLabelText`. Then put `myLabelText=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %.2dm %.2ds", pre, min, sec];` After that set this  text to your label like `myLabel.Text=myLabelText`